# Can we use images on tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see that on SO some tags have an image attached to them.
See these as example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android.

Can we do that on magento.stackexchange.com?
Or is it a feature available only after graduations?
Or do we need to ask for special privileges?

**[EDIT]**

I'm thinking we can make the tags look nicer.
I mean for [paypal](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paypal) use the paypal logo (Duh!)
For the [cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cart) use a small cart icon.
For specific payment or shipping methods use the logo (FedEx for example).
And the list can go on.

And  oh...you might express your opinion if this is a nice thing to have or we should just focus on the content of the website instead of small useless images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure we can't use it before graduation but it would be interesting to gather some ideas. What images you think can be used?

Comment: I've updated the post with some ideas and an additional question.